# Using binary search to find the last position of an element

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that returns the last position of an element in a sorted list, however I'm not quite sure of how binary search works. Can someone help me fix the problem in my code?

```
def last_entry(L, target):
    low = 0
    high = len(L) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if L[mid] < target:
            low = mid + 1        
        elif L[mid] > target:
            high = mid - 1        
        else:
            if mid == len(L) - 1:
                return mid
            if target < L[mid + 1]:
                return mid
    return -1
```

Comment: Can you *explain* what the problem is?

Comment: *last position of an element* what exactly you mean by it? Sample input and expected output would be really helpful.

Comment: can't you use `bisect` module?

Comment: I think I understand the problem: if your list is [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 8] and target is 3, you want to find the position of rightmost 3. In this case, it's 5.

Comment: Please post a sample input, expected output and actual output. Thanks

Comment: What part(s) of this code are meant to insure you find the last position?

Comment: To me, the problem is clear enough. I upvoted the question. The only little thing to improve is example of input, expected output and actual output

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
    else:
        if mid == len(L) - 1:
            return mid
        if target < L[mid + 1]:
            return mid
```

It's incomplete. If you use the input list [0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 8] and target 3, it will loop infinitely (I haven't tested it though). So you need to keep searching in the upper half for the target:

```
    else:
        if mid == len(L) - 1:
            return mid
        if target < L[mid + 1]:
            return mid

        low = mid + 1
```

**Edit:** I tested my solution and I think it works

Answer (score -1):

You can separate the problems. First we do the binary search, then we verify if it's the latest occurrence in list.

```
lst = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9]

def search(lst, target):
  min = 0
  max = len(lst)-1
  avg = (min+max)//2
  while (min < max):
    if (lst[avg] == target):
      return avg
    elif (lst[avg] < target):
      return avg + 1 + search(lst[avg+1:], target)
    else:
      return search(lst[:avg], target)
  return avg

def find_latest(lst, index):
    current = lst[index]
    index += 1
    while lst[index] == current:
        current = lst[index]
        index += 1
    return index - 1

find_latest(lst ,search(lst, 4))
```

Comment: This has linear complexity, but this problem can be solved logarithmically with a single binary search. Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: I don't see where is the linearity of my solution, but ok.

Comment: That's linear (you're scanning through an entire range of elements): while lst[index] == current:
        current = lst[index]
        index += 1